# Append String to List of Strings in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, append, list-comprehension

how can I append a string  to a  list  of strings, without using 
lists:append() . The code using list:append() is here, how to do the 
same using  list comprehension ?

```
S1 = "String1" . 
S2 = "String2" . 
S3 = "String3" . 
L1 = [ S1, S2 ] . 
L2 = lists:append(L1,[S3]).
```

The last line  yields the result

```
["String1","String2","String3"]
```

How to do this  using  list comprehension ?

Comment: Why do you want to list comprehensions for that?

Answer (score 3):

Look at Erlang documentation:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html

As told there - adding element to the tail of list is inefficient, because of it causes creating of new list.

If you need to add elements to the tail of list, better way may be: to create list in reverse order. And in the end just call function lists:reverse/1

Look at this example:

```
18> S1 = "String1". 
"String1"
19> S2 = "String2". 
"String2"
20> S3 = "String3". 
"String3"
21> S4 = "String4". 
"String4"
22> L1 = [ S2, S1 ].
["String2","String1"]
23> L2 = [ S3 | L1 ].
["String3","String2","String1"]
24> L3 = [ S4 | L2 ].
["String4","String3","String2","String1"]
25> L4 = lists:reverse( L3 ).
["String1","String2","String3","String4"]
```

It is more efficient in memory use than this one:

```
34> S1 = "String1". 
"String1"
35> S2 = "String2". 
"String2"
36> S3 = "String3". 
"String3"
37> S4 = "String4". 
"String4"
38> L1 = [ S1, S2 ].
["String1","String2"]
39> L2 = L1 ++ [ S3 ].
["String1","String2","String3"]
40> L3 = L2 ++ [ S4 ].
["String1","String2","String3","String4"]
```

( using '++' is equivalent of lists:append ).

In first example - only 2 instances of list has been created. And in second - 3 instances. In larger example results should been **2 list instances vs. N-1 instances**